# restrict access to custom settings

Tags: customsetting

Can we restrict access to the custom settings based on profile?

If I want to restrict some users from creating data in custom settings, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_add_data.htm&language=en_US), the permission needed to modify Custom Setting data is `Customize Application`. To prevent your users from modifying the Custom Settings in your organization, this will have to be disabled for all untrusted users.

[image: Customize Application]

This [knowledge article](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000194001) lists some of the other permissions gained from this profile permission.